# 500 error with mod re-write cannot see whats wrong?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have been using mod re-write ok up until now.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^/?(shopping-catalogue)/([0-9]+) index.php?friendly_url=$1&view=catalogue&catalogue_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(shopping-catalogue)/(category)/([0-9]+) index.php?friendly_url=$1&view=$2&category_id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(shopping-catalogue)/(category-item)/([0-9]+) index.php?friendly_url=$1&view=$2&category_item_id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(shopping-catalogue)/(category-item-option)/([0-9]+) index.php?friendly_url=$1&view=$2&category_item_option_id=$3 [L]

# marketing module see newsletter before sending
RewriteRule ^/?(newsletters)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(newsletter)\.html /newsletters/$2/newsletter.html [L]


RewriteRule .([^/]+)\.html index.php [L]


#RewriteRule ^/client-area/CLID/([0-9]+) /index.php?temp=template_dataroom&CLID=$1 [L]


# allow access with no restrictions to local machine at 192.168.1.3
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !192.168.1.3


# allow access to all .css and .js in sub-directories..
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js$

# allow access to the files inside img/, but not a directory listing..
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dataroom/(.*)\.
RewriteRule ^files/([^/]+)/([^/]+).zip /download.php?section=$1&file=$2 [NC]
# allow access to these particular files...
```

My problem seems to be that this line gets ignored

```
# marketing module see newsletter before sending
RewriteRule ^/?(newsletters)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(newsletter)\.html /newsletters/$2/newsletter.html [L]
```

I am trying to access an html file directly but the folder is a unique name each time.... ie -

```
http://www.awebsite.co.uk/newsletters/template_4fd09c5b429ea/newsletter.html
```

This line is being ignored. I do not understand why?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Andi

Comment: ok I updated it to include the underscore character now I get a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

ok I got it working now,. Took the / off the redirected link

Here is the line I now have

```
# marketing module see newsletter before sending
RewriteRule ^/?(newsletters)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/(newsletter)\.html newsletters/$2/newsletter.html [L]
```

Thanks

Andi

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the result but you do not seem to be allowing the underscore

```
RewriteRule ^/?(newsletters)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(newsletter)\.html /newsletters/$2/newsletter.html [L]

RewriteRule (newsletters)/([A-Za-z0-9|-|_]+)/(newsletter)\.html /newsletters/$2/newsletter.html [L]
```

Also, I don't think you need to starts with bit (^).